# pagination vs all data from server

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-mvc

In Angular 8+, If we need to display list of record, we will display result in pagination way.

We have more than 1 Million of Records and in future also record will increase.

I am using Spring Boot and MYSQL as a Database

But what would be the preferable approach

1. Getting all the data from server at once and handle Pagination at client side.
2. Get 10 Records at once and display and when User click at Next Button get the next 10 records from Server.

Comment: To store 1m records on the client is a huge perfomance mistake. I am absolutely sure the interface will not be accessible at all.

Comment: No 2 but also get the data in such a way that the data is received in the order most useful to client to avoid the need to go to the next page. No one wants to page through data unless absolutely required

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use Pagination as compared with all data from the server.

As you are getting all data from the server it is a costly operation as you mention your application has more than millions of records.

With the use of Pagination whenever required at that time API is called and get data based on your Pagination request per page.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly advise you to go with variant #2.

The main reason to do pagination is not really because it makes sense to only display a few entries in the UI at once. Instead, pagination allows you to only transfer the necessary entries from large data sets (such as yours). This greatly improves performance and reduces the amount of data that has to be sent from the server to the client.

Variant #1 will have very poor performance, because the client has to fetch all 1,000,000 records to then only display 10 of them. This does not make a lot of sense and goes directly against the idea and the advantages of pagination.

Variant #2 on the other hand will only fetch the entries that are actually displayed. And it will only transfer roughly 0.00001% of the data that variant #1 would.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something in between, load maybe 100 or 1000 records. But with one million you browser will go out of memory and with 10 your user gets bored...